# How do I define a cpp template of a range R and item type T of the range?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to define a template function that accepts a range and a function of the element type.

Something like so:

```
template<std::ranges::range R, R::element_t T>
void apply_on_pairs(const R &r, function<void(const T&, const T&)>f) { ... }
```

Where T is the element type or R.

How do I define T and R such that the relation above exist?
Or better yet, how do I define T in terms of R or R in terms of T?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`range_value_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iterator_t), which will deduce the element type of the range for you.

```
#include <functional>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

template<std::ranges::range R>
void apply_on_pairs(
  const R& r,
  std::function<void(
    const std::ranges::range_value_t<R>&, 
    const std::ranges::range_value_t<R>&)> f) { }

int main() {
  apply_on_pairs(std::vector{42}, [](auto, auto){});
}
```

Comment: Thanks!

Is there a way to avoid repeating "const std::ranges::range_value_t<R>&" ? e.g. putting it in the template

Comment: @user1656671 I don't think there is a way. Putting it in the template parameter list makes it impossible for the compiler to deduce the `std::function` type from the lambda.